# spreadsheet module for angular JS

Tags: angularjs-module

I am looking for a spreadsheet component to use in an Angular JS application. I found a tutorial on the web about making a spreadsheet using angualr, but I want something more advanced, for example with copy and paste feature. Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is that I have never seen any advanced spreadsheet component specifically built for angular and don't think one exists.

Options: You might try using Kendo's grid as a spreadsheet, or you could use a non-angular spreadsheet component and just manually retrieve the values when you're ready.  Unless you have a need for two-way binding with your sheet, having an angular-ized spreadsheet wouldn't gain you much that I can think of.

To hypothesize a bit further, my suspicion is that, except for small editable grids, you won't find such a thing.  Angular's performance is great for most apps, but with a spreadsheet, you'd have so many bindings that it would bog down quickly.  Here's just one article talking about some performance challenges in general.  Again, for most apps Angular is great and performance isn't a big issue.  You just happened to be asking about one for which it probably wouldn't be well-suited.

http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Btw, I'm guessing this is the example you found...

http://thomasstreet.net/blog/spreadsheet.html

If you're trying to just do something small like that, you could probably customize it a bit and be fine.  Capture keystrokes and implement copy and paste via the controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Wijmo's Flexgrid: http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/FlexGridIntro/FlexGridIntro/

We use it at my company and it has some great features.

Answer (score 3):

"for example with copy and paste feature" is a vague requirement.
So, just to name a few of the open-source AngularJs spreadsheet components out there:

- ngTable      [https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/ ]
- ngHandsontable   [https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable ]
- ngReactGrid  [https://github.com/josebalius/ngReactGrid ]
- Smart-Table  [https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table ]
- ng-grid / ui-grid [https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid ]

Commercial solutions would be for instance Kendo-UI or Wijmo